# Nokia Store download check for Nokia X

Tags: nokiax

Due to some security constraints I would like to implement a check to see the app was really downloaded from Nokia Store or not. If the app was not downloaded from Nokia Store the app will not run.

Is this possible? How can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know unfortunately  there are no mechanism for that.